# shell script invoke java, keep existing on linux

Tags: java

we have a bash shell script which invoke java program. will it be happened that the java ends/complete but the process of still on the process list?

below is the content of execute, which invoke a cronjob. since the cron job will check if the process end or not. if not end, it will not invoke.

crontab -l

```
55-59/60 1-23 * * * [ `ps aux | grep /var/local/ImportPO.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ] && sh /var/local/ImportPO.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

content of ImportPO.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting process ..";

JAR_DIR=/var/local/JavaLib8/
CLASS_PATH=/var/local/classes

JAR_LIB=
for i in $(ls $JAR_DIR)
do
        JAR_LIB=$JAR_LIB:$JAR_DIR$i
done

/usr/java/jdk1.8/bin/java -cp "$JAR_LIB:$CLASS_PATH" com.ExtractPORequest
```

## end of shell

while run> ps -aux, we still find the process exist (run over six hrs) even the java program completed and reach end of program. i use jps command to check, there is no existing on that java level process.

```
root     26091  0.0  0.0 106108  1192 ?        Ts   06:55   0:00 /bin/sh -c [ `ps aux | grep /var/local/ImportPO.sh | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ] && sh /var/local/ImportPO.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

root     26113  0.0  0.0 106112  1268 ?        T    06:55   0:00 sh /var/local/ImportPO.sh
```

Comment: Hi all, more infirmation that, the process become defunct after end of java program. how to prevent it?


26091 Tue Oct 24 06:55:01 2023    04:55:00 26091 /bin/sh -c [ `ps
26113 Tue Oct 24 06:55:01 2023    04:55:00 26113 sh /var/local/Pr
26124 Tue Oct 24 06:55:01 2023    04:55:00 26124 [java] <defunct>

Comment: Please edit you original question with further information, in comments section it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
root 26113 0.0 0.0 106112 1268 ? T 06:55 0:00 sh /var/local/ImportPO.sh
```

Here, the process state is `T`, which means "stopped by job control signal" according to the [`ps(1)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#PROCESS_STATE_CODES).

The reason for such a stop might be that someone has sent it a SIGSTOP, a SIGTSTP, or perhaps the Java process was trying to read from standard input (which cron jobs don't have unless some useful input is piped/redirected to them).

In the comments, you mentioned the process became defunct (i.e. a zombie process). "You can't do anything for the zombie, it's already dead. Instead, kill the evil zombie master!", or in other words, the problem is with the *parent* of the defunct process that is not checking the result code returned by its own child process.

If the parent of the defunct Java is your `ImportPO.sh` script, sending a SIGCONT to it might allow it to continue. If the PID of the process in the `T` state is 26113, then `kill -CONT 26113` would allow it to continue... and since starting the Java process is the last command in the script and the Java process has already ended, this should cause the script to exit immediately.